# Look for dates in a dataframe that are in list, grouping by ID

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an identification data frame with a series of years that represent the start of cycles, as such:

```
ID    YEAR1    YEAR2    YEAR3    YEAR4    YEAR5
1     2002     2004     2006     2008     2010
2     2006     2009     2012     2015     2018
...
```

and I have a main dataframe, which has the colum ID and also Year. I would like match the two dataframes in the following way: Create a new column 'start_cycle' and return 1 if for that ID, the Year column is any of the years in the identifying dataframe (any of the YEAR1, YEAR2, YEAR3...columns). Such as:

```
ID    YEAR    start_cycle
1     2005     0
1     2006     1
2     2006     1
2     2010     0
```

How could I do this? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.[https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html)

Comment: Your column start_cycle should have 1 if YEAR1, 2, 3, but 0 if YEAR 4,5 ?

Comment: No, sorry i tried to abbreviated it but any year value that matches any of the year columns on my first df. I got a good answer already though! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# convert df1 to ID - YEAR pair by stacking
df1_stacked = df1.set_index('ID').stack().rename('YEAR') \
         .reset_index(drop=False)[['ID', 'YEAR']] \
         .drop_duplicates()

# perform a left join of df2 with df1_stacked, if the value exists in both df2 and df1_stacked,
# it will have an indicator of both which should result in 1 for the start_cycle.
df2_with_indicator = df2.merge(df1_stacked, how='left', indicator=True) \
    .rename(columns={'_merge': 'start_cycle'}) \
    .assign(start_cycle=lambda df: df.start_cycle.eq('both').astype(int))

   ID  YEAR  start_cycle
0   1  2005            0
1   1  2006            1
2   2  2006            1
3   2  2010            0
```

[Working example](https://uscript.co/public/Google_108617488638529745626/python/7d925c36.py)

Answer (score 0):

**Data**

```
print(df)


ID  YEAR1  YEAR2  YEAR3  YEAR4  YEAR5
0   1   2002   2004   2006   2008   2010
1   2   2006   2009   2012   2015   2018

print(df1)



 ID  YEAR
0   1  2005
1   1  2006
2   2  2006
3   2  2010
```

**Solution**
melt `df` and check if the `value` is in `df1['YEAR]`. That will give you a `boolean` which you can convert to `integer`.

```
 df1['start_cycle']=df1.YEAR.isin(pd.melt(df, id_vars=['ID'],value_vars=['YEAR1','YEAR1','YEAR2','YEAR3'])['value']).astype(int)



  ID  YEAR  start_cycle
0   1  2005            0
1   1  2006            1
2   2  2006            1
3   2  2010            0
```